# Keep running count of selected items using jQuery and alert when limit reached

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

The following select box allows users to select the number of tickets they wish to purchase for a given rugby match.

There are potentially multiple rugby matches the user is entitled to purchase tickets for, hence the query loop.

As you can see, the id attribute of the select box has two dynamic values - the first one "currentrow" simply helps identify the particular select box we are dealing with. I have added "matchID" because we are implementing a new rule that states that the user cannot purchase more than 4 TICKETS PER MATCH PER TRANSACTION. Previously the limit was 4 TICKETS PER TRANSACTION regardless on the how many different matches they purchased tickets for.

```
<cfloop query="qEntitlements">
     <select class="quantity" name="qty_#currentrow#_#matchID#" id="qty_#currentrow#_#matchID#">
          <cfloop from="0" to="#qEntitlements.qty#" index="i">
               <option value="#i#">#i#</option>
          </cfloop>
     </select>
</cfloop>
```

So, I need the jQuery to keep a running count of the number of tickets the user selects PER MATCH and to fire an alert if it hits the limit for a given match.

The jQuery below works for the old rule of 4 tickets per transaction (simplified to remove any irrelevant processing):

```
function calcTotals(){
     var qty = 0;
     $('.quantity').each(function(){ 
          var thisline = thisid.split("_")[1];
          var thismatchid = thisid.split("_")[2]; // in preparation for new rule
          var thisqty = $('#qty_' + thisline + '_' + thismatchid  + ' option:selected').val();

          qty += Number(thisqty);

          // Limit to 4 tickets per order transaction
          // ToDo: Change this to 4 tickets per match per order
          if(qty > 4){
               alert('You are entitled to purchase a maximum of 4 tickets per order.');
               return false;
          } 
     })
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
     $(".quantity").change(function(e){
          calcTotals();
     })
})
```

You can see the current system working [on this page](http://www.allblacks.com/index.cfm?layout=ticketing&i=F2E4D996-E5A0-4843-A5D7-6990428A942C&c=72E3F0A3-C1D1-4BA7-92EB-4B28F0D63B6A).

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION

We need to tally the total qty for a given match because there may potentially be different seat categeories (e.g. Gold, Silver) for the same match.  See the example page I included in the OP. This is what a specified user sees (user is specified by the "i" param in the url). In this case, each row is for the same match, but different categories. Other users see different entititlements, which may be for multiple match/category combinations. .

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved it with the following code:

```
function calcTotals(){
     var qty = 0;
     var matchIDs = [];
     var matchOccurs = {};

     $('.quantity').each(function(i,selected){ 
          var thisid = $(this).attr("id"); 
          var thisline = thisid.split("_")[1];
          var thismatchid = thisid.split("_")[2];
          var thisunit = $('#unit_' + thisline).html();
          var thisqty = $('#qty_' + thisline + '_' + thismatchid + ' option:selected').val();

          if(thisqty > 0){
               matchIDs[i] = thismatchid;               
               // Limit to 4 tickets PER VENUE/EVENT per Transaction
               if (matchOccurs[matchIDs[i]] != null ) { 
                    matchOccurs[matchIDs[i]] += Number(thisqty); 
               }else {
                    matchOccurs[matchIDs[i]] = Number(thisqty); 
               }

               if(matchOccurs[matchIDs[i]] > 4){
                    alert('You are entitled to purchase a maximum of 4 tickets per match per order.');
                    $('#qty_' + thisline + '_' + thismatchid).val(0);
                    return false;
               }
          }
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like?

Quick question, why would you need to "store" the value if you just want to make sure the user doesn't select a qty greater than 4? If that is the case, why not limit the number of options in the dropdown? I am thinking I might misunderstanding your need here.

```
 $('body').delegate('select[id*="qty_"]','onchange', function(){
   if($(this).val() > 4){
      // what do you want to have happen here IF they choose more than 4?
   }
 })
```

or just using your code:

```
 $('select[id*="qty_"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() > 4){
       alert("too many tickets selected for event: " + $(this).closest('tr').first('td').text());
    }
  })
```

Comment: Good question. Answer: Because there may potentially be different seat categeories (e.g. Gold, Silver) for the same match, which would go on a separate row. See the example page I included in the OP. These options are for the same match, but have different categories. So, we actually need to tally the total for all rows having the same match.

Comment: In the example case, each row is for the same match but different categories. Other users see different entititlements, which may be for multiple match/category combinations.